# Нужно ли знать Java EE, чтобы быть более крутым Spring разработчиком?

Tags: java, spring, java-ee

Изучаю Spring и когда читаю всякие материалы или смотрю видео иногда поподается терминология из **Java EE**.
И вот я думаю, может стоит попутно изучать **Java EE**, чтобы иметь более углубленные и расширенные знания в **Spring** или это будет тратой времени?

Что подскажете?

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, что Spring и Spring Boot - это некая "современная альтернатива", или "свежий взгляд" на то, какой фреймворк использовать при разработке приложений.

То есть, исторически сначала возникла Java EE. Это был довольно монструозный фреймворк, к тому же, не совсем отвечающий требованиям разработки web-приложений.

И когда появился и достаточно развился Spring Boot - то это означало, что приложения enterprise-уровня можно теперь разрабатывать гораздо более простыми и естественными "для web" способами.

Поэтому Ваш вопрос - довольно философский: с одной стороны, знание двух фреймворков сразу - это, без сомнения, плюс. Например, Вы сможете участвовать в проектах по миграции старых приложений из Java EE на Spring Boot.

С другой стороны, освоение Java EE - это большой труд, и Вам все равно нужно будет выбрать тот фреймворк, который Вы изучите в первую очередь.

Причём, после этого второй фремворк будет изучать проще: будут аналогии, и Вы будете узнавать способы решения уже известных Вам (по первому фреймворку) задач.

Я бы сначала изучил Spring Boot, а потом принял уже более осознанное решение насчет Java EE.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, но мой вопрос скорее в другом. Я понимаю, что Java EE сейчас не в ходу. И изучать его как основной фреймворк я не собираюсь. Мне скорее интересует то, как изучение Spring Framework совместно с Java EE поможет мне иметь более глубокое погружение в Spring?

Comment: я бы осторожно сказал, что "я сомневаюсь". Мне кажется, там нет прямых аналогий, как в двух фреймворках, предназначенных для решения одной и той же задачи. Возможно, Вы можете сформулировать более конкреный вопрос, и Вам помогут более знающие, чем, товарищи?